# Calendario, for se salta una celda

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un calendario del mes actual en el que se está. Este calendario lo hago con un `for` y diferentes `if` según las condiciones que necesito.

En la primera fila me deja la última celda sin poner. No es que la ponga en blanco, es que no la pone.

Os dejo una captura de pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el código miro cuál es el primer día del mes (posición), pongo celdas en blanco hasta que se llega a la posición del primer día del mes y a partir de ahí empiezo a poner los días.

El total de celdas que tiene la tabla, contando los blancos del final es de 35.

Luego hago algunas comprobaciones del tipo "si el día es menor que el último día del mes", "si es el día actual" o "si existe alguna reserva para el día que está poniendo".

Os dejo el código donde `$i` es la celda por la que va y `$j` es el número de día por el que va:

```
    function dibujar_calendario($cal){
        $dia_actual = sprintf("%02d", date("d"));
        $mes_actual = sprintf("%02d", date("m"));
        $ano_actual = date("Y");
        $dias_mes_actual = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes_actual, $ano_actual);
        $nombre_mes_actual = strtoupper(strftime("%B"));
        $my_date = new DateTime();
        $my_date->modify('first day of this month');
        $pos_primer_dia_mes = $my_date->format('N');

        $xml = leer_reservas();
        $reservaArray = Array();
        $x = 0;
        foreach($xml->reserva as $reserva){
            $reservaArray[$x]["sala"] = $reserva->sala;
            $reservaArray[$x]["empleado"] = $reserva->empleado;
            $reservaArray[$x]["dia"] = $reserva->dia;
            $reservaArray[$x]["mes"] = $reserva->mes;
            $reservaArray[$x]["ano"] = $reserva->ano;
            $reservaArray[$x]["hora_inicio"] = $reserva->hora_inicio;
            $reservaArray[$x]["hora_fin"] = $reserva->hora_fin;
            $x++;
        }

        echo "<br><br><br>";
        echo "<center><span style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1.5em;'>".$nombre_mes_actual." ".$ano_actual."</span><br><br>";
        echo "<table><tr id='dias_semana'>";
        echo "<td>LUNES</td><td>MARTES</td><td>MIÉRCOLES</td><td>JUEVES</td><td>VIERNES</td><td>SÁBADO</td><td>DOMINGO</td>";
        echo "</tr><tr>";

        $j=1;
        for($i=1; $i<=35; $i++){
            if($i%7 == 0){
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            if($i < $pos_primer_dia_mes){
                echo "<td> </td>";
            } else {
                if($i == $pos_primer_dia_mes && $j <= $dias_mes_actual){
                    if($j < $dia_actual){
                        echo "<td id='dia_semana' style='background: #5F0800; color: #FFF;'>".$j."</td>";
                    }  else {
                        if(buscar_reserva($reservaArray, $j, $mes_actual)){
                            echo "<td id='dia_semana' class='".$cal."+".$mes_actual."+".$ano_actual."' onclick='ver_dia(this)' style='background: #FFFFC7;'>".$j."</td>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td id='dia_semana' class='".$cal."+".$mes_actual."+".$ano_actual."' onclick='ver_dia(this)'>".$j."</td>";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if($i > $pos_primer_dia_mes && $j <= $dias_mes_actual){
                        if($j < $dia_actual){
                            echo "<td id='dia_semana' style='background: #5F0800; color: #FFF;'>".$j."</td>";
                        }  else {
                            if(buscar_reserva($reservaArray, $j, $mes_actual)){
                                echo "<td id='dia_semana' class='".$cal."+".$mes_actual."+".$ano_actual."' onclick='ver_dia(this)' style='background: #FFFFC7;'>".$j."</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td id='dia_semana' class='".$cal."+".$mes_actual."+".$ano_actual."' onclick='ver_dia(this)'>".$j."</td>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $j++;
            }
        }
        echo "</tr></table>";
        echo "</center>";
    }
```

Os dejo lo que imprime en HTML:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo calculas `$pos_primer_dia_mes` y `$dias_mes_actual`?

Comment: Es posible que necesites cambiar el `if($i < $pos_primer_dia_mes){` por `if($i <= $pos_primer_dia_mes){` o quizá más bien **necesitas empezar por `$i=0`** en el bucle `for`. Sin el código completo, como bien indica @MauricioContreras , no podremos ayudarte con detalle.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Os dejo el código completo. Oscar el for no lo puedo empezar en 0 ya que la posición del primer día del mes me la da de 1 a 7. Y el if <= que me indicas, me empieza el primer día del mes en Sábado.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Os dejo el código completo arriba

Comment: Por favor @Juanjo , prueba con `for($i=0; $i<35; $i++)` y quita el último `<tr>` del `echo` anterior y me dices. En mis pruebas ha funcionado correctamente.

Comment: Ya he conseguido solucionarlo, os lo pongo en una respuesta. Muchas gracias @OscarGarcia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final, gracias al comentario de @OscarGarcia he podido solucionarlo, modificando un par de cosas más. He modificado `for($i=0; $i<35; $i++){` y luego en cada if `if($i+1 == $pos_primer_dia_mes && $j <= $dias_mes_actual){` e `if($i+1 > $pos_primer_dia_mes && $j <= $dias_mes_actual){`

Os dejo el código completo de todos modos.

```
    function dibujar_calendario($cal){
        $dia_actual = sprintf("%02d", date("d"));
        $mes_actual = sprintf("%02d", date("m"));
        $ano_actual = date("Y");
        $dias_mes_actual = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes_actual, $ano_actual);
        $nombre_mes_actual = strtoupper(strftime("%B"));
        $my_date = new DateTime();
        $my_date->modify('first day of this month');
        $pos_primer_dia_mes = $my_date->format('N');

        $xml = leer_reservas();
        $reservaArray = Array();
        $x = 0;
        foreach($xml->reserva as $reserva){
            $reservaArray[$x]["sala"] = $reserva->sala;
            $reservaArray[$x]["empleado"] = $reserva->empleado;
            $reservaArray[$x]["dia"] = $reserva->dia;
            $reservaArray[$x]["mes"] = $reserva->mes;
            $reservaArray[$x]["ano"] = $reserva->ano;
            $reservaArray[$x]["hora_inicio"] = $reserva->hora_inicio;
            $reservaArray[$x]["hora_fin"] = $reserva->hora_fin;
            $x++;
        }

        echo "<br><br><br>";
        echo "<center><span style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1.5em;'>".$nombre_mes_actual." ".$ano_actual."</span><br><br>";
        echo "<table><tr id='dias_semana'>";
        echo "<td>LUNES</td><td>MARTES</td><td>MIÉRCOLES</td><td>JUEVES</td><td>VIERNES</td><td>SÁBADO</td><td>DOMINGO</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $j=1;
        for($i=0; $i<35; $i++){
            if($i%7 == 0){
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            if($i+1 < $pos_primer_dia_mes){
                echo "<td> </td>";
            } else {
                if($i+1 == $pos_primer_dia_mes && $j <= $dias_mes_actual){
                    if($j < $dia_actual){
                        echo "<td id='dia_semana' style='background: #5F0800; color: #FFF;'>".$j."</td>";
                    }  else {
                        if(buscar_reserva($reservaArray, $j, $mes_actual)){
                            echo "<td id='dia_semana' class='".$cal."+".$mes_actual."+".$ano_actual."' onclick='ver_dia(this)' style='background: #FFFFC7;'>".$j."</td>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td id='dia_semana' class='".$cal."+".$mes_actual."+".$ano_actual."' onclick='ver_dia(this)'>".$j."</td>";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if($i+1 > $pos_primer_dia_mes && $j <= $dias_mes_actual){
                        if($j < $dia_actual){
                            echo "<td id='dia_semana' style='background: #5F0800; color: #FFF;'>".$j."</td>";
                        }  else {
                            if(buscar_reserva($reservaArray, $j, $mes_actual)){
                                echo "<td id='dia_semana' class='".$cal."+".$mes_actual."+".$ano_actual."' onclick='ver_dia(this)' style='background: #FFFFC7;'>".$j."</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td id='dia_semana' class='".$cal."+".$mes_actual."+".$ano_actual."' onclick='ver_dia(this)'>".$j."</td>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $j++;
            }
        }

        echo "</table>";
        echo "</center>";
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mi +1 :) me centré en las posiciones y los números de días, no el los otros `if`, por eso no los tuve en cuenta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Mi propuesta no pasa por analizar tu código, sino por mostrar una vía de solución más adecuada.

Existen varias clases ya hechas con las que puedes construir un calendario. Sería cuestión de pasar a esa clase el mes / año  y ella se encarga de crearte un calendario de forma correcta, de un mes en concreto o de un año completo.

El estilo del calendario lo puedes cambiar a tu gusto modificando las clases, las reglas CSS, los colores, etc.

Lo mismo los nombres de los meses, días, años, todo eso es muy fácil de cambiar.

Te dejo aquí un ejemplo. Si tienes problemas para adaptarlos puedes decirlo en comentarios.

Considero esto una mejor solución que intentar hacer funcionar un código que será siempre precario y poco automatizable.

De las que he visto, la que más me gusta es la clase de Chris Coyier, publicada en el artículo [*Build a Calendar Table*](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/build-a-calendar-table/) de  CSS Tricks.

Es cierto que el código se puede quizá modernizar un poco en cuanto a la forma de crear las fechas y demás, pero hace el trabajo que quieres en este caso.

#### La clase

La pongo tal cual, como está en la fuente (enlace de más arriba)

```
function build_calendar($month,$year,$dateArray) {

     // Create array containing abbreviations of days of week.
     $daysOfWeek = array('S','M','T','W','T','F','S');

     // What is the first day of the month in question?
     $firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

     // How many days does this month contain?
     $numberDays = date('t',$firstDayOfMonth);

     // Retrieve some information about the first day of the
     // month in question.
     $dateComponents = getdate($firstDayOfMonth);

     // What is the name of the month in question?
     $monthName = $dateComponents['month'];

     // What is the index value (0-6) of the first day of the
     // month in question.
     $dayOfWeek = $dateComponents['wday'];

     // Create the table tag opener and day headers

     $calendar = "<table class='calendar'>";
     $calendar .= "<caption>$monthName $year</caption>";
     $calendar .= "<tr>";

     // Create the calendar headers

     foreach($daysOfWeek as $day) {
          $calendar .= "<th class='header'>$day</th>";
     } 

     // Create the rest of the calendar

     // Initiate the day counter, starting with the 1st.

     $currentDay = 1;

     $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

     // The variable $dayOfWeek is used to
     // ensure that the calendar
     // display consists of exactly 7 columns.

     if ($dayOfWeek > 0) { 
          $calendar .= "<td colspan='$dayOfWeek'>&nbsp;</td>"; 
     }

     $month = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

     while ($currentDay <= $numberDays) {

          // Seventh column (Saturday) reached. Start a new row.

          if ($dayOfWeek == 7) {

               $dayOfWeek = 0;
               $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

          }

          $currentDayRel = str_pad($currentDay, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

          $date = "$year-$month-$currentDayRel";

          $calendar .= "<td class='day' rel='$date'>$currentDay</td>";

          // Increment counters

          $currentDay++;
          $dayOfWeek++;

     }



     // Complete the row of the last week in month, if necessary

     if ($dayOfWeek != 7) { 

          $remainingDays = 7 - $dayOfWeek;
          $calendar .= "<td colspan='$remainingDays'>&nbsp;</td>"; 

     }

     $calendar .= "</tr>";

     $calendar .= "</table>";

     return $calendar;

}
```

---

#### Uso

```
/*
     USO:
     Creando calendario del mes actual
*/
     $dateComponents = getdate();

     $month = $dateComponents['mon'];                
     $year = $dateComponents['year'];
     $dateArray=null;
     echo build_calendar($month,$year,$dateArray);

/*
```

---

#### Salida

Tendrías esto. He modificado de forma sencilla la clase `day` en el CSS. Lo bueno es que puedes adaptar las clases CSS para aplicar cualquier plantilla de calendario que quieras. Las hay super interesantes que muestran activo el día actual, los domingos diferentes, etc...

```css
     .day{
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.24);
      margin-top: 5px;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 30px 40px 40px;
     }
```

```html
    <table class='calendar'>
        <caption>
            February 2019
        </caption>

        <tr>
            <th class='header'>S</th>
            <th class='header'>M</th>
            <th class='header'>T</th>
            <th class='header'>W</th>
            <th class='header'>T</th>
            <th class='header'>F</th>
            <th class='header'>S</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='5'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-01'>1</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-02'>2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-03'>3</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-04'>4</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-05'>5</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-06'>6</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-07'>7</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-08'>8</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-09'>9</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-10'>10</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-11'>11</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-12'>12</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-13'>13</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-14'>14</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-15'>15</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-16'>16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-17'>17</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-18'>18</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-19'>19</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-20'>20</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-21'>21</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-22'>22</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-23'>23</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-24'>24</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-25'>25</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-26'>26</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-27'>27</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2019-02-28'>28</td>
            <td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

---

#### Código en línea

Puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN](https://rextester.com/ECKS75160)**</kbd> del código en línea y hacer pruebas sobre él.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu gran respuesta. Ya había visto varias clases para crear un calendario, pero al final he optado por crearlo desde cero.